# writing a driving simulation and i want to use three commands at once to keep cars single file in a three patch road

Tags: netlogo

This is for a car to not pass a car in front or in front to the left and to the right. how can i use all commands, how do i link them?

```
  to place-cars-level0                                    ;creating basic real life driver

 ;make a random placement of cars
  ask n-of (num-of-cars-level0 / 3) patches with [meaning = "road-up"] [
    if not any? cars-on patch pxcor (pycor + 1) and not any? cars-here and not any? cars-on patch pxcor (pycor - 1) and not any? patches with [meaning = "crossing"] in-radius 2 [
  sprout-cars 1 [
    set size 3
    set will-turn? "maybe"
    set will-stop? "maybe"
    set shape "car top"
    set politeness basic-politeness + random (101 - basic-politeness)
    if random 100 > basic-politeness [set politeness random 21]
    set heading 0
    let s random 10
    if s < 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 15 + random 16]
    if s = 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 20 + random 6]
    if s > 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit + random 16]
    set speed maxSpeed - random 20
  ]
]
]    ; set the number of cars for the level, size, politness,speed

 ask n-of (num-of-cars-level0 / 3) patches with [meaning = "road-down" and count turtles-on neighbors = 0] [
if not any? cars-on patch pxcor (pycor + 1) and not any? cars-here and not any? cars-on patch pxcor (pycor - 1) and not any? patches with [meaning = "crossing"] in-radius 2 [
  sprout-cars 1 [
    set size 3
    set shape "car top"
    set politeness basic-politeness + random (101 - basic-politeness)
    if random 100 > basic-politeness [set politeness random 21]
    set heading 180
    set will-turn? "maybe"
    set will-stop? "maybe"
    let s random 10
    if s < 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 15 + random 16]
    if s = 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 20 + random 6]
    if s > 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit + random 16]
    set speed maxSpeed - random 20
  ]
  ]
  ]

   ask n-of (num-of-cars-level0 / 3) patches with [meaning = "road-left" and 
 count turtles-on neighbors = 0] [
  if not any? cars-on patch (pxcor + 1) pycor and not any? cars-here and not 
any? cars-on patch (pxcor - 1) pycor and not any? patches with [meaning = 
"crossing"] in-radius 2 [
  sprout-cars 1 [
    set will-turn? "maybe"
    set will-stop? "maybe"
    set size 3
    set shape "car top"
    set politeness basic-politeness + random (101 - basic-politeness)
    if random 100 > basic-politeness [set politeness random 21]
    set heading 270
    let s random 10
    if s < 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 15 + random 16]
    if s = 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 20 + random 6]
    if s > 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit + random 16]
    set speed maxSpeed - random 20
  ]
   ]
  ]

  while [count cars < num-of-cars-level0] [
  ask one-of patches with [meaning = "road-right"] [
  if not any? cars-on patch (pxcor + 1) pycor and not any? cars-here and not 
any? cars-on patch (pxcor - 1) pycor and not any? patches with [meaning = 
"crossing"] in-radius 2 [
    sprout-cars 1 [
      set will-turn? "maybe"
      set will-stop? "maybe"
      set size 3
      set shape "car top"
      set politeness basic-politeness + random (101 - basic-politeness)
      if random 100 > basic-politeness [set politeness random 21]
      set heading 90
      let s random 10
      if s < 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 15 + random 16]
      if s = 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit - 20 + random 6]
      if s > 7 [set maxSpeed speed-limit + random 16]
      set speed maxSpeed - random 20
    ]
        ]
    ]
  ]

  end
```

in the section above is the code for writing the car placement and below is the speed and control

```
to control-speed
let car-ahead one-of cars-on patch-ahead 4
ifelse car-ahead = nobody  [
  ifelse speed < maxSpeed [set speed speed + acceleration] [set speed speed 
- deceleration]
]
[
ifelse [speed] of car-ahead = 0 [set speed 0] [
  ifelse [speed] of car-ahead >= maxSpeed [
    set speed maxSpeed
    set speed speed - deceleration
  ] [
  ;try to overtake
  ;ifelse [meaning] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 = meaning and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 and [meaning] of patch-left-and-ahead 90 1 != "crossroad"
  ;and meaning != "crossing" and [meaning] of patch-left-and-ahead 180 1.3 != "crossing" and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 169 3
  ;and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 45 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 135 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 23 2
 ; and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 157 2 and not any? turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 12 3 and [meaning] of patch-ahead 1 != "crossing" [move-to patch-left-and-ahead 90 1] [


   ; ifelse [meaning] of patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 = meaning and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 90 14 and [meaning] of patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 != "crossroad"
    ;and meaning != "crossing" and [meaning] of patch-right-and-ahead 180 1.3 != "crossing" and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 12 3
    ;and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 45 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 135 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 23 2
    ;and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 157 2 and not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 169 3 and [meaning] of patch-ahead 1 != "crossing"[move-to patch-right-and-ahead 90 1] [
      ;set speed [speed] of car-ahead
      ;set speed speed - deceleration]
  ]



  ]
]
```

i hope this is more useful[the image shows the overall simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av8Nb.png)

if you can see the image, my aim is to keep one car in each lane rather then three side by side per lane, this is to simulate semi autonomous vehicle lane centering

Comment: This is unfortunately very unclear. If you are trying to make sure a car can't pass other cars, then we need to see the code you are using to move cars. After all, you will need logic that is something like 'go forward unless there is a car that you can't pass'

Comment: JenB i have added more detail i hope you can help me

Comment: okay, so overtaking is not the problem i think. Please confirm that your road lanes are 3 patches wide and you are currently getting cars 'sharing the lane', that is, they don't crash into each other if directly behind, but they do end up next to each other. If this is true, please show just the section of code that stops them from ramming directly from behind, because what you want is for the front car to be seen as occupying all three patches instead of just the one it's on.

Comment: that would be idea if i can get the car in front to say that it occupies all three patches, yes each lane is made up of three patches.@JenB the line that stops them crashing into the one in front of them is the second section of coding starting at~~~~~~~~
    let car-ahead one-of cars-on patch-ahead 4
ifelse car-ahead = nobody  [
  ifelse speed < maxSpeed [set speed speed + acceleration] [set speed speed 
- deceleration]
]
[
ifelse [speed] of car-ahead = 0 [set speed 0] [
  ifelse [speed] of car-ahead >= maxSpeed [
    set speed maxSpeed
    set speed speed - deceleration
  ]~~~~~~~

Comment: in sorry that didnt comment how i thought it would, its the second line of the second section ~~~let car-ahead one-of cars-on patch-ahead 4~~~

Answer (score 1):

Okay, instead of doing

```
let car-ahead one-of cars-on patch-ahead 4
```

what you probably want to do is create a patch-set of all the three patches that a potential car could be occupying. That's a little difficult without knowing how you have created the lanes, and you need to be careful because the car doing the asking could be in any of three patches too. After creating that patchset, you can simply do what you did before but using the patch-set.

```
let in-lane (patch-set patch-ahead 4 <other patches you need go here>)
let car-ahead one-of cars-on in-lane
```

Comment: thank you that helped with that problem, however i have some more problems